# How to create a PDF from highcharts graph and a table with PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf, highcharts

I have 2 highcharts graphs and 2 tables that shows the results. I want to print both of them on separate sheets on a PDF file with PHP. It should support CSS3 and HTML5.

I checked dompdf but it only supports CSS 2.1 and some CSS 3 properties.

Thanks in advance

Comment: provide more details please

Comment: On left side I have a highcharts graph and on the right side I have a table with some values. I want to print this on PDF

Comment: Please take look at the related topic [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table)

Comment: Thank you for the site but I also need to export my tables I mean extra html in the same PDF. At the moment I'm working on html2canvas + jspdf to create them as images If I can manage it I'll let you know :)